# Using A PHP variable within An SQL statement

Tags: php, sql

I am very new to PHP and SQL... 
I cant get variables used within my SQL code to be recognised ?

here is the full code, i am trying to populate a database table with answer to questions answered from a html page

any help please?

```
<?php

$odbc = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'root', '') or die ("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db('Questionaire', $odbc) or die ("can not find database");

$sql;
$quantity = 1;

$id = 222;
$r = 1;
$course = '555';



for ($i = 1; $i < $quantity; $i++)
{   
$answer = $_POST['q'.$r];

if ($answer == 'a')
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `questionaire`.`tanswer` (`User`, `QuestionID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, `Answer3`, `Answer4`, `Answer5`, `AnswerFreeText`) VALUES (".$id.", ".$i.",       '1', '0', '0',  '0', '0', '')";                         
}

if ($answer == 'b')
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `questionaire`.`tanswer` (`User`, `QuestionID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, `Answer3`, `Answer4`, `Answer5`, `AnswerFreeText`) VALUES ('.$id.', '.$i.',               "0", "1", "0",  "0", "0", "")'; 
    echo'<h2> hello </h2>'; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$odbc) or die ("can not run query");                 
}

if ($answer == 'c')
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `questionaire`.`tanswer` (`User`, `QuestionID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, `Answer3`, `Answer4`, `Answer5`, `AnswerFreeText`) VALUES (".$id.", ".$i.",       '0', '0', '1',  '0', '0', '')";     echo $sql;                  
}

if ($answer == 'd')
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `questionaire`.`tanswer` (`User`, `QuestionID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, `Answer3`, `Answer4`, `Answer5`, `AnswerFreeText`) VALUES (".$id.", ".$i.", '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '');";                           
}

$r++;

}



?>
```

Comment: Where do you define `$id` and `$i`?

Comment: If you are new forget everything about `mysql_` and start using `mysqli` or `PDO` as long as you still have not memorized to much. Than have a look at prepared statements.

Comment: is `$id` a string or an integer? if it's a string, you're introducing syntax errors.

Comment: inb4 beware of sql injection attacks...   if the variables you are using are not integers, put them in single quotes first like `'".$variable."'`

Answer (score 3):

If you're new to PHP and MySQL you would do well to learn best practices early, and adopt the habit of using query parameters.  This is much easier than using `.` to concatenate PHP variables into SQL.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO(...connection parameters...);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `questionaire`.`tanswer` 
    (`User`, `QuestionID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, `Answer3`, `Answer4`, `Answer5`, `AnswerFreeText`) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql) 
    or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo, true));

$values = array($id, $i, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, '');

$stmt->execute($values) 
    or die(print_r($stmt->errorInfo, true));
```

It's easier to code, *and* it avoids the risk of [SQL injection](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies) vulnerabilities.

You can use a query parameter in place of a single literal value in an SQL expression.  So, you can't use parameters for a table name, column name, a list of values, or other syntax.  Only where you would otherwise write a single string or a single number in your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should put all variables in single quotes (try and produce something like: "('1', 'John', 'Canada', etc...). In order to do so you should use something like:

```
"... VALUES ('$id', '$i', '0', etc...)"
```

Tip:

The double-quotes means the text is first parsed, which makes it possible to integrate variables straight into it.

Suppose i = 1. That produces:

```
 "i is: $i" == "i is: 1";
```

If you want, however, to have the direct text you've used WITHOUT parsing it first you can use a SINGLE quote ('):

```
 'i is: $i' == 'i is: $i'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something simpler for you:

```
      $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table " .
               " (id, col1, col2,col3) " .
               " VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s', '%s');",
               mysql_real_escape_string($val1),
               mysql_real_escape_string($val2),
               mysql_real_escape_string($val3));
```

Comment: No one should use the deprecated ext/mysql API.